# Android opencv stream IP Camera

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have searched for many hours but not found the answer to my problem. I have successfully stream an IP camera to android with rtsp connection but it is without the use of opencv library. Is it possible to stream IP camera on android with the help of opencv? I mean in the opencv, it uses the android built in camera but what I wanted is that to use the IP camera instead of the built in one. And on the opencv for android samples, it uses JavaCameraView (XML) and the way to access is using CameraBridgeViewBase. Is there a way to set it based on the IP of the IP camera? I have seen some examples using VideoCapture but on swing only. I'm confused on how to integrate VideoCapture on to CameraBridgeViewBase. I'm sorry I'm so noob. Please can someone help me.

Comment: atm, opencv cannot read any kind of video on android, neither from file, nor from ip (it would need some c/c++ backend , like ffmpeg for this)

Comment: @berak Hello thank you for answering! Oh okay it's so sad to hear that. I have one last thing to ask to you if that's okay. Is it possible to manipulate IP camera stream on android using other libraries? Thank you so much.

Comment: @berak what I meant is that for motion detection, counter, etc.

Comment: sorry, no expert on this here. i just noticed the painful absence, same as you.

Comment: I am also looking for the same thing but still has no luck :(

Comment: Any updates on this feature?